# Como conectar serverless y dynamoDb en Docker

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, dynamodb

no se como conectar 2 contenedores docker, no logro hacer que se comuniquen entre ellos

mis servicios deberian correr en `3000`
y mi base de datos dynamo local en `8000`

este es el error que me arroja

```
Error:
UnknownEndpoint: Inaccessible host: `localhost' at port `8000'. This service may not be available in the `localhost' region.
    at Request.ENOTFOUND_ERROR (/usr/src/app/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:576:46)
```

**Template de dynamoDB**

```
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    networks:
      - dynamodb-network

networks:
  dynamodb-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Mi conexión a `DynamoBD`

```
const dynamoDBClient = new DynamoDB({
  endpoint: "http://localhost:8000",
});
```

esto es lo que tengo en serverless

```
plugins:
  - serverless-offline
  - serverless-dynamodb-local
  - serverless-s3-local

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs16.x

custom:
  parameters:
    ORDER_TABLE_NAME: ordenes
    INVOICE_BUCKET_NAME: comprobantes

  dynamodb:
    stages:
      - dev
    start:
      port: 8000
      inMemory: true
      heapInitial: 200m
      heapMax: 1g
      migrate: true
      seed: true
      convertEmptyValues: true
      noStart: true

  s3:
    host: localhost
    directory: /tmp
```

comando para levantar servicio

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name serverless_offline --network dynamodb_dynamodb-network serverless_offline
```